# part of script in html not running

Tags: javascript, html

i want to show a key whenever the data being looked at is after a date, when running, the line

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 1234;
```

works fine, but the line

```
text.style.display = "none";
```

does not seem to have any effect on hiding the key

```js
var curdate=new Date();
var startdate = new Date(2018, 5, 0);
var text = document.getElementById("key");
if(curdate.getTime() >= startdate.getTime()){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 1234;
  text.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="key" style="display:block">{{show-key}}</p>
```

I made the style.display work using a checkbox as a temporary solution, but after changing to the date system i can't figure out why the line wont run.(I'm still new to html and JS, so sorry if this is a stupid question, couldn't find anything about it.)

Comment: This code is working fine. Perhaps you have duplicate ID of "key" and only the first one is hiding.

Comment: after messing with it more, i can get hidden text to show from inside the script, but it still wont work with the {{show-key}}. it's weird to me because i could make it work when i was using a checkbox to change it back and forth. maybe it has something to do with calling the script?